# Getting an Import Error when importing rasterio

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, rasterio

I have been having trouble installing Rasterio, finally got that installed, but now I am getting an error on the import in Spyder.  Below is the console output for the error.

> runfile('C:/Users/eolson/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/eolson')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\eolson\untitled0.py", line 9, in 
>       import rasterio
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\eolson\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasterio__init__.py",
>   line 22, in 
>       from rasterio._base import gdal_version
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be
>   found.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new environment in anaconda, then follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/rasterio-feedstock):

In the anaconda command prompt:

1. `conda config --add channels conda-forge`
2. `conda install rasterio`